# Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Permission denied in command line. hadoop

Tags: hadoop, permission-denied, word-count

```
ramubuntu@ubuntu:~$ hadoop jar ./wordcount.jar com.hadoop.ram.wc.WordCountDriver /input /output

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:115)
```

i also tired to change permissions of jar n folders..
i written code using eclipse . under Java 6 version .. but i installed Java 8 in my Ubuntu.. while creating Java project i changed jre to 1.6..

file owner is current user only. i hope you understand my problem

Comment: do you have permission to write output in output folder and read the data from input folder. check that too

Comment: i did still the same result.. n im using hadoop 1.x verison @Kanagarajdhanapal . i check JPS , n found that secondary name node is not get started.. is that the reason ? for this exception ..?

Comment: check your hadoop folder permission.

Answer (score 0):

is selinux enabled? try disabled it first

## setenforce 0